# Setting Google Analytics to use custom Source Key for Campaigns

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-analytics, uri

I have a campaign I will am looking to track the source for in Google Analytics and I have a URL structure setup with the respective advertising outlets and the code listed below to map the `src` parameter to the URI structure I have setup but for some reason I am not seeing the records in the Google Analytics admin.  The Snippet I am using is from the [HTML5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com) and the documentation for the Google Analytics `_setCampSourceKey` is [here.](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiCampaignTracking.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCampSourceKey)

**URI STRUCTURE**

sample-uri.com/enter-to-win/?src=campaignSource

**GOOGLE ANALYTICS ON PAGE**

```
var _gaq=[['_setAccount','XX-XXXXX-X'],['_setCampSourceKey', 'src'],['_trackPageview']];
(function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.async=1;
  g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
```

Does this look like it is setup correctly?  Thank you in advance

JN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is setup correctly. Just try it out. If you view your cookies, you'll see the value you put in `src` is documented in the `__utmz` cookie, in the `utmcsr` subvalue:

> __utmz=163456314.1320168230.1.1.utmcsr=campaignSource|utmccn=(not%20set)|utmcmd=(not%20set);

That value should appear in your "Source" report in your "Traffic Sources" section in Google Analytics. It might take up to 24 hours for those values to appear, though.

Comment: Thanks @yahelc I thought this seemed to be correct but did not really know how to check it.  I just viewed my cookies and it was there. Thanks for this insight and help!

Answer (score 0):

See where it says "XX-XXXXX-X" that should be your google analytics tracker id for your website. It all relies on that.

Login to analytics, go to analytics settigns, and you'll see the code you need to sue. It starts with UA for all of mine.

Comment: I did not want to post my GA code to the live site, hence the XXXXX. I have the correct GA Tracker installed.

Comment: The analytics account, it's not an old one that doesn't use async?